# How to plot a function in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am struggling with plotting a distribution in Netlogo. 
After defining the distribution `P(b)` as `(1+a)*(1-b)`, where `a` is an integer number between `0` and `5` (that we can change by using a slider) and `b` is a random float between `0` and `1`, for each turtle,  I should plot it. 
On the x-axis there should be `b`, while on y-axis `P(f)`.

I tried to plot it in the following way:

```
set-current-plot "Distribution"
plot [P_distribution] of turtles
set-plot-x-range 0 (max [b] of turtles)
```

but there is something wrong because it does not plot anything.

I would like to graph a line plot where I can show how P(b) changes with b. 
Could you please show me how to do this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
ask turtles [
  plotxy b P_distribution
]
```

If you want a scatter plot, you'll need to edit the plot, edit the plot pen, and set it to point mode.